# Scrape ticker sector information from Yahoo finance

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, finance, yahoo-finance

I got an error message when I try to scrape the "Sector" from a ticker in Yahoo finance.
I tried to follow the library manual advising to select the correct parent and child info from the HTLM page, but I could not capture the "sector" of the ticker (for example: [for the `AAPL` ticker the sector is `Technology`](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile?p=AAPL)):
[image]

Below is the sector's html code (view source):
[image: Yahoo website page and html code]

Here is my attempt:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile?p=AAPL'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
sector_element = soup.find('span', text='Sector(s)').find_next('span', class_='Fw(600)')
print(sector_element.text)
```

I was expecting to get `"Technology"` but instead got the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set correct `User-Agent` HTTP header to get right response from server:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0'}

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile?p=AAPL'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
sector_element = soup.find('span', string='Sector(s)').find_next('span', class_='Fw(600)')
print(sector_element.text)
```

Prints:

```
Technology
```

Comment: Thanks, how did you find that changing User-Agent would solve the issue?

Comment: @Matiouz123 `User-Agent` is common header that some servers require. So it's the one of first thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

Hi It's my first time that helping to someone :D

```
element = soup.find('div',class_='Pos(r) Bgc($bg-content) Bgc($lv2BgColor)! Miw(1007px) Maw(1260px) tablet_Miw(600px)--noRightRail Bxz(bb) Bdstartc(t) Bdstartw(20px) Bdendc(t) Bdends(s) Bdendw(20px) Bdstarts(s) Mx(a)')
span_tag = element.find('div',id='Main').find('div',id='mrt-node-Col1-0-Profile').find('div',id='Col1-0-Profile-Proxy').find('section',class_='Pb(30px) smartphone_Px(20px)').find('div',class_='asset-profile-container').find('div',class_='Pt(10px) smartphone_Pt(20px) Lh(1.7)')
span_tag2 = span_tag.find('div',class_='Mb(25px)').find('p',class_='D(ib) Va(t)').get_text()
print(span_tag2)
```

Sector(s): TechnologyIndustry: Consumer ElectronicsFull Time Employees: 164,000

Comment: I hope you interpret this as purely helpful newcomer guidance, I'd like to give you a friendly welcome and thank you for proving a helpful answer.

FYI Stack Overflow is aware its your first time commenting, and community does review it it, hence this feedback.

Your answer is fine: I would advise you could improve it by removing the qualifier about it being your first answer and just focus on providing the best answer you can.

Furthermore the standard review response for any answer that looks like this, i.e. just a code block. I please provide some explanation or commentary on the code, e.g.